# Why did I receive -35 points rep with comment "user was removed"

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

Tonight I appear to have received -35 points because a user was removed. What did I do wrong ? I don't think I have done anything recently on this particular forum ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when a user upvotes someones posts and then deletes his account. All upvotes (and downvotes) are undone. (I got -100 yesterday, presumably via the same user.)

So, you didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: That should be made more clear in the tag.  I thought *I* had been removed.  Be still my beating heart.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford If you look at your reputation, you'll see the text 'User was removed (learn more)'. The 'learn more' link contains a good explanation.